# Why is my Drupal 8 CORS setup not working?

Tags: jquery, ajax, drupal, cors, drupal-8

Since Drupal 8.2 the cors setup is in core. In my `services.yml` (and `default.services.yml`) I have the following setup:

```
cors.config:
    enabled: true
    # Specify allowed headers, like 'x-allowed-header'.
    allowedHeaders: ['x-csrf-token','authorization','content-type','accept','origin','x-requested-with']
    # Specify allowed request methods, specify ['*'] to allow all possible ones.
    allowedMethods: ['*']
    # Configure requests allowed from specific origins.
    allowedOrigins: ['*']
    # Sets the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header.
    exposedHeaders: false
    # Sets the Access-Control-Max-Age header.
    maxAge: 1000
    # Sets the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header.
    supportsCredentials: true
```

My domain `a.com` is htaccess password protected.

On domain `b.com` I try to load some API from domain `a.com`:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  xhrField: {
    withCredentials : true
  },
  beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic Z2VuaXVzOmNvYXRpbmdz');
  }
});

request = $.ajax({
  url: apiBaseUrl + 'api/foobar',
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'get',
  password: 'foo',
  username: 'bar'
});
```

In chrome it works fine, in firefox I get an error. The request headers:

```
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization
```

Response is 401 "Authorization required", it says request method is OPTIONS (?).

Whats wrong here?

Doing the same request in [insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/) works perfectly fine.

Comment: Are you certain the problem you’re seeing in Firefox isn’t just because it’s loading a cached copy of the document that it cached before you added the CORS config on the server side? Have you tried clearing your browser cache in Firefox?

Comment: And to be clear about why you’re seeing an indication that the request method is OPTIONS: that’s because the presence of the the Authorization request header in the request triggers your browser to automatically make a CORS preflight OPTIONS request https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests before it attempts the GET request your code is trying to send.

Comment: The reason the request works in insomnia is because no restrictions are imposed on insomnia’s ability to make cross-origin requests, while in contrast browsers will block your frontend JavaScript code from being able to access responses from cross-origin requests unless those responses include the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header and any other necessary CORS response headers. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS has the details

Comment: i dont understand a word you guys :D

@sideshowbarker yep, I cleared the cache and set to disable network cache with dev tools is open

Comment: I have no idea why the request would be working in Chrome, unless maybe you’re running Chrome with `--disable-web-security` or something. Otherwise if you add more details to the question—such as what requests your browser is sending and what responses it’s receiving, and the actual request and response headers that your browser devtools Network pane shows—then it might be possible to figure out more.

Comment: in firefox one of my 5 ajax json requests wouldnt work when in that specific `$.ajax()` call (or object), additionally to the `withCredentials` inside the `ajaxSetup`, `username` and `password` value pairs are present. chrome and safari ignored those obviously, while firefox wouldnt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Response is 401 "Authorization required", it says request method is OPTIONS (?).

You need to configure your server backend to not require authorization for `OPTIONS` requests.

That 401 response indicates the server is requiring authorization for an `OPTIONS` request, but authorization is failing because the request doesn’t contain the required credentials.

The reason is, that `OPTIONS` request is sent automatically by your browser as part of CORS.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests explains in general why browsers make CORS preflight `OPTIONS` requests, but in the specific case in the question, the reason is because the request contains the `Authorization` request header.

So what’s happening is:

1. Your code’s telling your browser it wants to send a request with the `Authorization` header.
2. Your browser says, OK, requests with the `Authorization` header require me to do a CORS preflight `OPTIONS` to make sure the server allows requests with the `Authorization` header.
3. Your browser sends the `OPTIONS` request to the server **without the `Authorization` header**, because the whole purpose of the `OPTIONS` check is to see if it’s OK to include that header.
4. Your server sees the `OPTIONS` request but instead of responding to it in a way that indicates it allows the `Authorization` header in requests, it rejects it with a 401 since it lacks the header.
5. Your browser expects a 200 or 204 response for the CORS preflight but instead gets that 401 response. So your browser stops right there and never tries the `GET` request from your code.

So you need to figure out what part of your current server-side code is causing your server to require authorization for `OPTIONS` requests, and you need to change that so that it instead handles `OPTIONS` requests without authorization being required.

Once you fix that, the existing `cors.config` shown in the question should cause the server to respond to the `OPTIONS` request in the right way—with an `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` response header that includes `Authorization`, so that your browser can then say, OK, this server allows cross-origin requests that contain the `Authorization` header, so I’ll now go ahead and send the actual `GET` request.

Comment: I swear to god thats exactly what I tried. I also added `SetEnvIfNoCase Request_Method OPTIONS allowed` but it didnt work in the first place. Still, thanks for that nice round-up!

Comment: i still got problems in firefox. in the network tab i see that the response actually returned the valid json, but in jQuery it gives me an error, i.e. it goes into the `fail` instead of `done` function. The `statusText` is error, without any further `responseText`

Comment: If Firefox isn’t seeing the right CORS response, it’s expected that you’d still be able to see the response in the devtools network tab. But just because you can see it there doesn’t mean Firefox will allow your code to access the response. Firefox will only let you get to the response if it sees Access-Control-Allow-Origin in the response, with the right value.

Comment: Anyway, to further isolate the problem one thing you could consider is writing up the request code using the fetch(…) method directly rather than jQuery $.ajax. I’m not super familiar myself with the effects of the various options that jQuery $.ajax has—what those cause behind the scenes—but I am a lot more familiar with troubleshooting problems with the native fetch()

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to the working CORS configuration and htaccess setup:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_Method OPTIONS noauth
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Require valid-user
Allow from env=noauth
Satisfy Any
```

you have to make sure that your ajax setup does not have the `withCredentials` and `password` and `username`, like in my question. This leads to errors in Firefox, at least. Working ajax:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  xhrField: {
    withCredentials : true
  },
  beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic foobarbarfoo');
  }
});

request = $.ajax({
  url: isApiActive ? apiBaseUrl + 'api/mydata' : './mydata.json',
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'get'
});
```

Comment: Genuinely glad to hear you figured out a complete fix and glad I can quit letting it worry me too :) (And would upvote this answer in celebration right now except that I’m already out of upvotes for the day—so will circle back around in ~14 hours and do it then.)

Comment: my last comment under your answer was that i figured it out, hope you didnt oversee that :D thanks again mate!